# C Math pow(): unexpected results

Tags: c, math, pow

Consider the following code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%f\n", pow(43,10));
}
```

This outputs: 21611482313284248.000000

See http://codepad.org/eSa4ASF2 for playground.

But if I run the operation with Windows Calculator (x^y function) I get this result:
21611482313284249

What's happening??

Comment: precision, precision, precision.

Comment: Could you better explain? Which is the correct result?

Comment: the question linked to , explains well.

Comment: Obviously,the windows calculator output is perfect!

Comment: Why has been downvoted?? I understand it's duplicated (even if I've looked for duplicates before with no success...), but there's no need of downvoting it for this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IEEE-754, `double` (binary-64) can represent all integers exactly up to `9007199254740992` (that is 2 power 53). After that not all integer numbers can be represented exactly in a `double`. Your number  `21611482313284249` is greater than `9007199254740992` and cannot be represented exactly in a `double`.

Answer (score 3):

The result is so large, the significand of a double-precision float does not contain enough precision to represent every integer.